# Wamp server not able access in internet after changing the port

Tags: php, apache, port, wamp, httpd.conf

I have changed the port number in apache in bitnami wamp stack by following changes in httpd.conf file.

```
Listen 8083
```

ServerName localhost:8083

After changing the server is not able to access in interenet. In localhost it is showing the home page.

I have added the :8083 after the ip address.Can anyone please help on this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `ServerName localhost:8083` just `ServerName localhost`. In browser:
`localhost:8083`